# как разбить вывод команды powershell на ключи с значениями (node js) по типу ключ: значение

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell

Итак, имеется команда powershell `Get-Vm`

Я разбил вывод на массив и получил нужные мне значения.
(Методом научного тыка выяснил что мне не нужны первые 3 элемента массива, а последние 2 пустые)

---

Вывод команды без разбития на массив:

```
[32;1mName      [0m[32;1m State  [0m [32;1;3mCPUUsage(%)[0m [32;1;3mMemoryAssigned(M)[0m[32;1m Uptime          [0m[32;1m Status            [0m[32;1m Version[0m
[32;1m----      [0m [32;1m-----  [0m [32;1m-----------[0m [32;1m-----------------[0m [32;1m------          [0m [32;1m------            [0m [32;1m-------[0m
Portainer  Running 0           6442              05:50:52.0410000 Работает нормально 11.0
Windows-11 Off     0           0                 00:00:00         Работает нормально 11.0
```

---

Вывод команды после разбития на массив:

[image: элементы массива]

---

И очищенный от ненужных строк массив:

[image: очищенный массив]

---

Суть вопроса в том, что бы разбить каждый элемент массива на объект json по типу `ключ: значение`

Например:

```
[{
    vm_name: "Portainer",
    vm_state: "Running",
    cpu: "0",
    memory: "6442",
    uptime: "05:50:52.0410000"
    status: "Работает нормально"
    version: "11.0"
},{
    vm_name: "Windows-11",
    vm_state: "Off",
    cpu: "0",
    memory: "0",
    uptime: "00:00:00"
    status: "Работает нормально"
    version: "11.0"
}]
```

Вот только я понятия не имею как это сделать.
Я видел вариант с `split()`, но не допер, смогу ли я использовать это в своём случае

P.S.:
Код избиения массива:

```
var array = msg.payload
var i
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    array.shift()
}
array.length = array.length - 2
return msg;
```

P.P.S.:
Кодер из меня такой себе, я ещё только учусь

Если это важно, то проект сделан на Node-RED
вот так выглядит последовательность:

[image: Логика]

Comment: мне кажется, что к этой задаче нужно подойти иначе. я бы искал способ убрать обозначения цветов из консольного вывода, а то и преобразования в csv, как тут https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-powershell/how-to-get-csv-output-for-get-vm-and-get-vmnetworkadapter/m-p/2213779 только без записи в файл csv, а с выводом в output

Comment: @nörbörnën Спасибо за ответ. я попробовал изменить команду что бы получить определённые значения, однако столкнулся с той же проблемой вывода... команда: `Get-VM -Name * & Select-Object -Property Name,State,CPUUsage`, вывод: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/C9e4eHyy)

Comment: можно конечно записывать в csv, а потом читать от туда, но выглядит как мартышкин труд

Comment: в примере `Get-VM -Name * | Select-Object -Property Name,State,CPUUsage | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation`. я не могу запустить её, так что пока мой ответ не ответ, а гипотеза

Comment: без параметра -path команда просто упадет в ошибку `Export-Csv : You must specify either the -Path or -LiteralPath parameters, but not both.`

Comment: вот так вот выглядит результат выполнения команды с указанием назначения. Name,"State","CPUUsage"
Windows-11,"Off","0"
Portainer,"Running","0"

Comment: на конвертацию в csv: я нагуглил  https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv

Comment: на результат выполнения: хотите больше полей, очевидно же, перечислите их в Select-Object

Comment: спасибо большое, сейчас попробую

Comment: Действительно работает. Я очень вам благодарен) А как теперь это сопоставить в `ключ: значение` ?

Comment: нужно взять какую-то библиотеку, простую и быструю, из https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=csv. но вообще, я вам нагуглил https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json. думаю, можно обойтись простейшим JSON.parse. И ещё можно попробовать Select-Object убрать из команды, наверное без него будут все поля объекта

Comment: без Select-Object выводит уж слишком много, я сошелся к такой команде: `Get-VM -name * | Select-Object -Property Name,State,CPUUsage,MemoryAssigned,Uptime | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation`. Вывод: `"Name","State","CPUUsage","MemoryAssigned","Uptime"
"Windows-11","Off","0","0","00:00:00"
"Portainer","Running","0","6591348736","07:19:36.0180000"`

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет использовать `ConvertTo-Json` это и вправду полностью решает мою проблему. Единственная оставшаяся проблема, это то что node обрезает полученное сообщение и добавляет в конце "..." хотя powershell позволяет просмотреть вывод целиком

Comment: решил проблему тем, что добавил парсер json в самом node-red

Comment: добавьте -Compress в ConvertTo-Json, возможно это сделает вывод json более компактным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо огромное @nörbörnën за помощь (фактически он решил мою проблему)

Всё оказалось куда проще, чем я думал:

---

Вместо команды `Get-Vm` и разбивки на массив, мне посоветовали использовать `Get-VM -name * | Select-Object -Property Name,State,CPUUsage,MemoryAssigned,Uptime | ConvertTo-Json`, что сразу выдало мне нужный ответ.

Так же для правильного отображения вывода команды в node-red я добавил парсер json и получил полный вывод:

---

```
[{
    "Name":"Windows-11",
    "State":3,
    "CPUUsage":0,
    "MemoryAssigned":0,
    "Uptime": {
        "Ticks":0,
        "Days":0,
        "Hours":0,
        "Milliseconds":0,
        "Microseconds":0,
        "Nanoseconds":0,
        "Minutes":0,
        "Seconds":0,
        "TotalDays":0,
        "TotalHours":0,
        "TotalMilliseconds":0,
        "TotalMicroseconds":0,
        "TotalNanoseconds":0,
        "TotalMinutes":0,
        "TotalSeconds":0
    }
},{
    "Name":"Portainer",
    "State":2,
    "CPUUsage":0,
    "MemoryAssigned":6591348736,
    "Uptime":{
        "Ticks":269882980000,
        "Days":0,
        "Hours":7,
        "Milliseconds":298,
        "Microseconds":0,
        "Nanoseconds":0,
        "Minutes":29,
        "Seconds":48,
        "TotalDays":0.31236456018518516,
        "TotalHours":7.496749444444444,
        "TotalMilliseconds":26988298,
        "TotalMicroseconds":26988298000,
        "TotalNanoseconds":26988298000000,
        "TotalMinutes":449.80496666666664,
        "TotalSeconds":26988.298
    }
}]
```

---

Вот так вот и решилась вся проблема

P.S.:
Вот так выглядит итоговая логическая цепочка в Node-RED:

[image: Логика]